# Teradata dividing data from one column to other columns side by side with different condition

Tags: sql, teradata

Anyone knows the solution for dividing data like this?

Table select:

```
select P_Name, L_Flag, C_Flag
from DWH.X_DWH_P_Data_Xxxx_Xxx
where P_Name like '%XXXX%'
and C_Flag like 'M';

+---------------------+--------+---------+
|       P_Name        | L_Flag | C_Flag  |
+---------------------+--------+---------+
|  xx_XXXX_CZE_H_xx   |   Y    |    M    |  
|  xx_XXXX_HUN_H      |   Y    |    M    | 
|  xx_XXXX_CZE_H_xxxx |   Y    |    M    |
|  xx_XXXX_GER_H_x    |   Y    |    M    | 
|  xx_XXXX_GER_H      |   Y    |    M    |
|  xx_XXXX_GER_H_xxxx |   Y    |    M    | 
|  xx_XXXX_CZE_H_xx   |   Y    |    M    |
|  xx_XXXX_SWE_H_xx   |   Y    |    M    |
|  xx_XXXX_CZE_H_xx   |   Y    |    M    |
|  xx_XXXX_SWE_H_xxxx |   Y    |    M    | 
+---------------------+--------+---------+
```

I need select to see table like this:

```
+-------------------+--------+---------+-------------------+--------+---------+
|       P_Name      | L_Flag | C_Flag  |       P_Name      | L_Flag | C_Flag  |
+-------------------+--------+---------+-------------------+--------+---------+
| xx_XXXX_CZE_H_xx  |   Y    |    M    | xx_XXXX_GER_H_x   |   Y    |    M    | 
| xx_XXXX_CZE_H_xxxx|   Y    |    M    | xx_XXXX_GER_H     |   Y    |    M    | 
| xx_XXXX_CZE_H_xx  |   Y    |    M    | xx_XXXX_GER_H_xxxx|   Y    |    M    |
| xx_XXXX_CZE_H_xx  |   Y    |    M    |-------------------+--------+---------+ 
+-------------------+--------+---------+
```

sort it with the P_Name (Country_code) column to another columns (there will be 12 countries side by side)

Help please.

Comment: Is there a relationships between record `xx_XXXX_CZE_H_xx  |   Y    |    M` an record `xx_XXXX_GER_H_x   |   Y    |    M ` specifically? If there isn't then you can't put them side by side. That would be a task for excel, not a database. I assume there isn't since your first 3 columns has 4 records and your second 3 columns has only 3. That's just not something a database does, but it is something that excel might do, or you might do on a website via HTML.

Comment: Most of record has the same string with the difference in country code so you can find here xx_XXXX_CZE_H_xx and xx_XXXX_GER_H_xx but it's not enough for relationship which you are asking for. Excel would make it I am sure, I just wanted to solve it here somehow because I had instructions to try it...I am glad I found out at least this solution.

Comment: When there's a known number of countries and you got a rule to determine the P_Name groups, e.g. `substr(P_Name, 1,13)` you can add a `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY substr(P_Name, 1,13) ORDER BY whatever)` and then use conditional aggregation and `GROUP BY rownumber` (or Pivot if you got a newer TD release)